# Generating dropdown from list

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I have a website with a file structure that looks like this

```
website
|
|-data 
  | 
  |-clients.txt
| 
|-website
  |
  |--index.html
```

My clients.txt file is a list of clients in the structure

```
Coke
Pepsi
Sprite
```

etc. There is about 100 clients that change so I don't want to hard code them. Is there a way for bootstrap to read the file and generate the dropdown? The html currently looks like this

```
<div class="wrap-input100client input100-select col-6">
    <span class="label-input100">Client</span>
        <div>
        <select class="selection-2" name="service">
        <option>Pick a Client</option>

        </select>
        </div>
    <span class="focus-input100"></span>
</div>
```

Have tried this but it doesn't give anything unfortunately

```
<div class="wrap-input100client input100-select col-6">
    <span class="label-input100">Client</span>
        <div>
        <select class="selection-2" name="service">
        <option>Pick a Client</option>

        <script>
            $filename = '../data/clients.txt';
            $eachlines = file($filename, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
            echo '<select name="value" id="value">'
            foreach($eachlines as $lines){
            echo "<option>{$lines}</option>";
                }
            echo '</select>';
        </script>

        </select>
        </div>
    <span class="focus-input100"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Hi BenM, added current attempt in the edit. thanks

Comment: You're aware that's PHP code, right?

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery, you can try like below code

```
$.get('data/client.txt', function(data) {    
    var lines = data.split("\n");    
    $.each(lines, function(n, elem) {
       $('.selection-2').append('<option value="'+elem+'">' + elem + '</option>');
    });
});
```

use full path for text file

Comment: Hi Jeswin, tried your suggestion inbetween the the <script> tags (with full path) and no joy unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Use `XMLHttpRequest` to get file content, change file path according to your folder structure.

```
  var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    rawFile.open("GET", "/Files/data/test.txt", false);
    rawFile.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (rawFile.readyState === 4) {
            if (rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0) {
                var allText = rawFile.responseText;
                allText = allText.split('\n');
                $.each(allText, function (i, item) {

                    $(".selection-2").append("<option value='" + item + "'>" + item + "</option>");
                });
            }
        }
    }
    rawFile.send(null);
```